# How can I reset the loop counter to each rows?

Tags: vba, loops, counter, ms-word

I am new to VBA. I'm creating a program which will attach the image according to the value of the 3rd `Cell` of the table (`Cell3Text`). The `Cell3Text` corresponds to the file name of the image files in "images" folder. For example, the *15-001* on the first rows has *15-001r1.jpg*, *15-001r2.jpg*, *15-001r3.jpg*,..and so on. Each rows have different number of image files (*r1, *r2, *r3).

I have counter of files using loop here. But on the next row, the counter adds to the count previous row. How can I reset the loop counter to each rows?

```vb
Sub ContinuousCounter()

Set tbl = ActiveDocument.Tables(1)

Dim Cell3Text As String
Dim Cell1Text As String
   Dim imgDir As String
   Dim receiptsImg As String
   Dim count As Integer

For Idx = tbl.Rows.count To 1 Step -1
    tbl.Cell(Idx, 1).Range.Select

    Cell3Text = tbl.Cell(Idx, 3)
    Cell3Text = Left$(Cell3Text, Len(Cell3Text) - 2) ' Remove table cell markers from the text.
    Cell1Text = tbl.Cell(Idx, 1)
    Cell1Text = Left$(Cell1Text, Len(Cell1Text) - 2) ' Remove table cell markers from the text.
    imgDir = ActiveDocument.path & "\images\"
    receiptsImg = Dir(imgDir & Cell3Text & "r*.jpg")

    Selection.EndKey Unit:=wdRow, Extend:=True
    Selection.MoveRight Unit:=wdCharacter, count:=2

    If Len(Cell3Text) = 6 And receiptsImg <> "" Then


        While receiptsImg <> ""
            count = count + 1
           Selection.TypeText Text:=Chr(11)
           Selection.InlineShapes.AddPicture _
             FileName:=imgDir & receiptsImg, _
             LinkToFile:=False, SaveWithDocument:=True
             Selection.TypeText Text:=Chr(11)
           ' Get next file name.
           receiptsImg = Dir()
        Wend
        MsgBox count 'debugger only. shows the number of files containing "r" according to 3rd cell in a row
                    ' but seems every loop adds to the previous count
    Else

      MsgBox "No scanned image for " & Cell3Text & ". otherwise it is improperly renamed."

    End If



 ' ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::BREAK ROWS::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::

    If Len(Cell3Text) < 2 Then ' if the 3rd cell is blank then turns into header
        tbl.Cell(Idx, 1).Select
        Selection.Rows.Delete
        Selection.InsertBreak Type:=wdColumnBreak  ' or Type:=wdPageBreak
        Selection.TypeText Cell1Text

    Else
        tbl.Cell(Idx, 1).Select
        Selection.Cells.Delete
        Selection.InsertBreak Type:=wdColumnBreak  ' or Selection.SplitTable

    End If

Next

End Sub
```

[image: Picture]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apologies if I am oversimplifying your problem, but do you not just need to do the following:

```
If Len(Cell3Text) = 6 And receiptsImg <> "" Then

    count=0'Reset the counter for a new matching cell

    While receiptsImg <> ""
        count = count + 1
        ...
    Wend
    MsgBox count 'debugger only. shows the number of files containing "r" according to 3rd cell in a row
                ' but seems every loop adds to the previous count
Else

  MsgBox "No scanned image for " & Cell3Text & ". otherwise it is improperly renamed."

End If
```

Comment: Thank you very much. Now that i found out that the solution is very simple. Shame on me.